# xfrun4 alternative for Linux Mint Cinnamon

Tags: linux, linux-mint, hotkeys, launcher

I just switched from Xubuntu to Linux mint cinnamon and am trying to find an application launcher to replace xfrun4. What are the options that exist these days?

Ideally, it would be a text box with autocomplete as I use hotkeys to call it up and would prefer to not use the mouse if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look into Synapse. I think it's pretty much what you are looking for.

Comment: This works great!